# Why claim a terrain on singleplayer mode?

Tags: medieval-engineers

Is there any advantage of paying taxes to own land if you are the only non-NPC player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Steam post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/333950/discussions/0/2592234299547126328/) has a reply from the developers stating that is primarily for multiplayer only.

> it's mostly for multiplayer gameplay, if you pay the taxes (at the claim block) it protects all creations (house/castle) in your area.

Aside from this, reading over the [game wiki page for claim blocks](https://medievalengineerswiki.com/w/Claim_Block) doesn't seem to indicate anything useful for singleplayer.